# Trouble deploying Unity build to Xbox One dev mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox, xbox-one

This is the error I'm getting.

> The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '192.168.1.3'.': MissingMethodException - Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity.RemoteDevice.Ping()'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a wrong windows SDK witch could be installed by VS custom installing. You can try uninstall "Windows Software Development Kit" on "program and feature", and install one here: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Maybe you need fix your solution by missed feature when you open your project again.